# How can I get Windows 7 firewall from being stuck in public network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

A few weeks ago, my Windows 7 Firewall switched itself from a private network to a public network. I noticed the problem when I was trying to stream a movie from my computer to my TV (as I did dozens of times before) and it wouldn't work. Under my network and sharing center, I have the network as a home network, however windows firewall absolutely will not budge from public.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete the network altogether. When you reconnect to the network again, it will be recreated and you should be able to choose.

Comment: Sometimes this is easier said than done lol... Be prepared to possibly do this a few times if it simply won't change... been there, done that. Most of the time it should work as expected but on occasion it may take a little more work.

Comment: Agreed Chris! :)

Comment: Some detailed instructions or source data to backup your answer would be a great improvement here.

Answer (score 0):

The network can get stuck in `Public` in Windows 7.

> This issue can occur if you have at inadvertently selected the
>   checkbox beside the option to Treat all future networks that I connect
>   to as public, and don’t ask me again. Once this option is set, you may
>   be unable to change this setting.

Microsoft has acknowledged this and has a `Fix It` available at the link below. Or you can follow these steps.

1. Close or suspend any applications that uses the network.
2. Click `Start`, type `device manager` in the `Search programs and files`
   box, and then press `Enter`
3. Browse list of devices and click to expand `Network adapters`
4. Right-click on the first adapter under Network Adapters and click
   `Disable`. (Repeat this step for all network adapters on your system under Network Adapters). **Note:** After each change, Device Manager will rescan your hardware. Your monitor may blink when refreshed, this is expected.
5. While still in Device Manager, re-enable only the adapter that’s associated with the public-network setting that you are trying to change. (Example, if you’re trying to connect to your wireless network, enable the wireless adapter.) **Note:** Your system will notice your network reappearing and try to connect. This connection attempt may fail, but that’s ok, this is expected.
6. Click Start, and type `Network and sharing Center` in the Search programs and files box, and then click `Network and Sharing Center`, from the list
7. In the lower left side of the dialog box, click `Choose homegroup and sharing options`.
8. Click `What is a network location?`, and select your network location. **Note:** If you want to continue setting up a homegroup, follow the remaining prompts. But a homegroup isn’t required, so you also can simply exit the homegroup setup after you select the correct network location.
9. The last step is to re-enable your remaining adapters, one by one in Device Manager. To do this simply Right-click each of the disabled adapters under Network Adapters and click `Enable`.
10. When all Network Adapters are enabled, close the Device Manager and you're done.

Source - [Windows 7 Network connections are stuck in Public mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2578723)